# Have Xamarin Studio treat some warnings as errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

In Xamarin Studio, is it possible to have the compiler treat certain warnings as errors? I would like to elevate the severity of some warning so I am forced to see and deal with them. I am using the Mac version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is a normal C# project then you can select which warnings you want to be treated as errors in the Build/Compiler page in the project's properties. In the "Additional arguments" field enter:

```
-warnaserror:CS0123,CS3210
```

To make the warnings CS0123 and CS3210 be treated as errors.